# how to manipulate bit of integer type in c?

Tags: c, casting, bit-manipulation

I have written this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct A {
  bool a;
  bool b;
  bool c;
  bool d;
};

struct B {
  int a;
};

int main() {
  struct A* pa = malloc( sizeof(struct A) );
  struct B* pb = (struct B*) pa;
  pa->a = 0;
  pa->b = 1;
  pa->c = 0;
  pa->d = 0;

  printf("value of pint is %i\n", pb->a);
  return 0;
}
```

I expect that it print 2 (0010) but the output is 256. Any one cloud help that what is wrong with this code?

Comment: %i will print a number, thats why

Comment: bools aren't bits. If you want a bitfield, use a bitfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you initialize `pa`, you have

```
*pa = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

since each bool is one byte. And when you type cast this into an int value, you get (in little endian machine) `*pb` as

```
*pb = 0x00000100
```

which is obviously `256`. Got it?

If you want, you may define `struct A` as:

```
struct A {
  bool a:1;
  bool b:1;
  bool c:1;
  bool d:1;
};
```

but do not typecast a pointer of `struct A` to that of `struct B` since both structures's sizes are then different.

This may be helpful to you in future:

```
union A {
    struct {
    bool bit0:1;
    bool bit1:1;
    bool bit2:1;
    bool bit3:1;
    bool bit4:1;
    bool bit5:1;
    bool bit6:1;
    bool bit7:1;
    };
    unsigned char cByte;
};
```

By defining so, you can access this as bit-wise or byte-wise.

Comment: Yes of course, I have found this article very useful http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/

Answer (score 3):

> I expect that it print 2 (0010) but the output is 256. Any one cloud help that what is wrong with this code?

A `bool` takes up at least one byte. In your case, apparently exactly one byte, and your platform is little-endian (with 8-bit `char`). So the second (least significant) byte is 1, all other bytes 0, makes `1*256`.

Note that the type-punning via `pa` and `pb` violates strict aliasing.

Use a `union` to portably type-pun.

Answer (score 1):

`%i`   prints an integer.

bool is an unsigned integer type large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

You can print a bool this way:

```
printf("%d\n", b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the number in little Endian notation.  Effectively, what you printed is:

```
0 * 256^0 + 1 * 256^1 + 0 * 256^2 + 0 * 256^3
```

If you decide to use bitfields (as suggested by someone else), you should use `%x` to print in hexadecimal.  If you strictly want to print in binary, you will have to do it using a loop going over individual bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
struct A {
  bool a:1;
  bool b:1;
  bool c:1;
  bool d:1;
};
```

the `:1` part force compiler alloc 1 bit instead of 1 byte for each member variable, so the memory layout of struct A will look like this one (assume little endian):

```
|-byte 1-|-byte 2-|-byte 3-|-byte 3-|
 uuuudcba uuuuuuuu uuuuuuuu uuuuuuuu
```

where `u` donates for unused. when cast it to integer, you will get an integer view of:

```
uuuuuuuu uuuuuuuu uuuuuuuu uuuudcba
```

And because of different bit-order of different compiler implementation, you may get also get reversed result 4 (0100) instead of 2 (0010)

Comment: Did you notice the cast to int later? Can you add what is going to happen when it is done??

Comment: Note bitfield ordering is completely up to compiler (high-to-low or low-to high) and habe nothing to do with endianness.